# Using a value from an Input, do a Select using that value, then return a json to an autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm new to Json, Ajax and Jquery, so this is turning out very frustrating.
I'm doing a code to autocomplete on a form using Jquery. My form consists in 4 elements:

1) Client

2) Requestor

3) Address

4) Email

So far, I can autocomplete the Client with this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#Client").autocomplete({
                    source:'getClient.php',
                    minLength:1
                });
            });
    </script>
```

However, I need to get the next data (Requestors, Address...) using the Client's values instead of showing all the requestors and all the addresses from the database.

I've been trying for 3 hours and I just don't seem to get any data.
As an example, I've just set my Requestor input with an onclick.

```
<input type="text" name="Req" size="60" id="Reqt" onclick="getreq()"><br>
```

This was the last code attempt I've done so far:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
 function getreq(){
            //get the username
    var Client = $('#Client').val();
    //use ajax to run the check
           $.ajax({
            data:  Client,
            url:   'getReq.php',
            type:  'post',

            success:  function (response) {
                    $("#Reqt").autocomplete({
                    source:'getReq.php',
                    minLength:1
                });
            }
    });
   }
});
    </script>
```

And my PHP looks like this

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
 mysql_select_db("test");

 $client = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Client']);

 $query=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM client WHERE Clients ="'.$client.'"');
 $json=array();

    while($Reqt=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $json[]=array(
                    'value'=> $Reqt["Requestor"],
                    'label'=>$Reqt["Requestor"]
                        );
    }

 echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Like I said, I've been trying this for hours and I'm pretty new to Json, Ajax and Jquery, but I need to use those technologies, I would really appreciate any and all insight. Thanks in advance!

Comment: any console errors when `getreq()` is fired? (f12 or right click > inspect element to check)

Comment: What error you are facing. Can you be more specific

Comment: I'm getting  Uncaught ReferenceError: getreq is not defined